# Encrypted and authorized multicast

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, multicast

I have a server (will be noted as 'A') that transmits multicast to some end stations.
I would like only those that are privileged to see the information, to actually see it.

There is a third party server ('B') that manages unicast communications with both 'A' and the end stations and SSL with both of them.

My goal is to implement a secured multicast:
Two necessary givens:

1. It has to be multicast.
2. I want the security in the Application level (not the Network or Transport)

---

Questions:

1. Are there such implementations? I've tried searching for "secured multicast" etc. and have come across only IP Multicast security. I want an applicative implementation. If so, Could you recommend some and how to use them?
2. I thought about generating a special symmetric key - during the communication of 'A' and 'B' and during the conversation of 'B' and end station = to pass it (over SSL) to the end stations.

   a. Is that a good idea?

   b. A problem I see is that revealing the key becomes easier because of the amount of stations. I thought about replacing the key every hour. I shall inform the stations the key has changed by sending multicast messages: (sequence_number, encrypted_message) - this way every time the key changes then sequence_number++.

What do you think of the implementation? Have better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an app called UFTP (http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) that does exactly this.

In terms of key management, each multicast session performs a TLS-like key exchange between the sender and each receiver, then uses the negotiated key for each receiver to send out the group key which is used to encrypt the data.  By doing key negotiation for each session, this eliminates complications related to re-keying mid session.

Authentication is done via key fingerprinting, with fingerprints being communicated out-of-band.  This is simpler than a certificate based system and minimizes overhead.  Each sender and receiver has an RSA or ECDHA key they are identified by.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a simple application of PKI:

- Each station creates an RSA keypair and sends its public key to the server.
- The server generates a random symmetric key and encrypts the multicast message using this symmetric key. New symmetric key should be generated for each message but usually it's not a big deal.
- The symmetric key is encrypted using each station's public RSA key. Products of all such encryptions (i.e. encrypted session keys) are merged with encrypted data and compose the multicast packet.

Unfortunately such scheme will cause a significant extra data load on the multicast message, but this is caused by length of keys and the length can't be reduced without sacrificing security.